# How to make a local variable into a global in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I make a local variable inside a function into a global in JavaScript?

P.S: Just pure JavaScript, no jQuery.

P.P.S.: Nothing toooo complicated, thanks. :)

Comment: do you mean declaring a global variable inside a function?

Comment: just remove `var` before variable declaration

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat Ok, tnx for finding that... I retracted my close vote... now let us close it against the correct dupe...

Comment: @sbedulin Please don't do that. It's *The Horror of Implicit Globals*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following to access a global inside of a function.

Any variable created outside the scope of a function can be referenced inside of a function.

```
Var myGlobalVar;

Function myFunction(){
   if(....) {
        myGlobalVar = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: This helped in my situation.

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

You can *copy* a local variable to the global scope by doing `window.myVar = myVar` (replacing `window` by whatever is your global object), but if you reassign the local one, the global copy won't follow.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a key to the `window` object. It'll be a global variable.

```
function foo(){
   var bar1; // Local variable
   bar1 = 11;
   window.bar2 = bar1; // bar2 will be global with same value.
}
```

**Or**

In pure JavaScript, if you will declare a variable without `var` anywhere, it will be in the global scope.

```
function foo(){
   var bar1; // Local variable
   bar1 = 11;
   bar2 = bar1; // bar2 will be global with same value.
}
```

**Note:** In the above text, if `bar2` won't be declared yet, it will go to the `window` scope, otherwise it will just update `bar2`. If you want to make sure about using the global one, use like `window.bar2 = bar1`.

Comment: That's not a declaration, that's just an assignment to a non-local variable.

Comment: @Bergi but it will be in global scope.

Comment: …as long as it was not declared in a (non-global) parent scope of `foo`.

Comment: @Bergi updated the answer, thanx, actually I was not thinking that there will be other code also.

Comment: That's *The Horror of Implicit Globals*. Better avoid it. And it won't work in strict mode.